# Ubuntu 12.04 desktop freezes, or rather the mouse recognition

Tags: 12.04, unity, mouse

I have a problem. The Ubuntu desktop freezes in a way, that I can still type, do everything on the keyboard but the mouse doesn't work. I can move it around but it doesn't highlight anything in the launcher and the mouse buttons don't do anything. Can anybody please help me?

Thanks

Comment: What hardware is your computer? I discovered some irregularities in the UI and now consider a 3GHz Core2Duo to be not enough for 12.04.

Comment: @EliahKagan yes, but that question got answered in a way I'm happy with. :) I do agree with you but this helped me decide the lowest spec CPU I'll buy for my business henceforth is a Core i3.

Comment: Thanks. I have a Samsung NC10 Plus laptop with a 1.66GHz Atom processor, 1GB RAM, and Intel 3150 graphics card. Is it enough for Ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: Try xubuntu 10.04 live CD or USB... if the performance is snappy in that environment, then probably not enough cpu. :( At work we do have 2 Ubuntu machines on 1.66 Atoms and they're at least stable and usable for any single task.

Comment: I installed Gnome-Shell and it runs a little bit better. But still, I would expect this machine to run good; is there anything I can do to make it work faster? Are the Intel graphics drivers in use the latest ones?

Comment: try hitting alt+tab a couple of times, I've had the mouse glitch if i'm trying to drag files sometimes, happened in unity and gnome. I would recommend xubuntu for a computer like that.

Answer (score 2):

In xorg.conf I changed the Option "Protocol" for Input Device "Mouse" from "auto" to "Microsoft" and my problems with auto clicking and mouse freezing have completely cleared up.

Answer (score 0):

you need to restart the touchpad/mouse interface using

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse
```

this removes mouse interface from linux kernel .
then

```
sudo modprobe psmouse
```

this adds mouse interface to linux kernel